# How to extract the middle part of a string in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a proteomic data frame with several columns. One of them is a called Description, in which we have the name of protein, OS, gene name (GN), PE, and SV, as I shown below.

```r
> head(pccmit$Description)
[1] "Protein NDRG4 OS=Homo sapiens GN=NDRG4 PE=1 SV=2"                                   
[2] "V-type proton ATPase subunit B_ brain isoform OS=Homo sapiens GN=ATP6V1B2 PE=1 SV=3"
[3] "Serotransferrin OS=Homo sapiens GN=TF PE=1 SV=3"                                    
[4] "Glutaminase kidney isoform_ mitochondrial OS=Homo sapiens GN=GLS PE=1 SV=1"         
[5] "Adenylate kinase isoenzyme 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=AK1 PE=1 SV=3"                      
[6] "Sideroflexin-1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=SFXN1 PE=1 SV=4"
```

Then, I'd like to extract just the gene name of that proteins

I've tried to use the :str_extract tool, however, it is not working. Maybe because i'm not using the correct pattern required by the tool

```r
str_extract(A$Description, start = "GN=", end = " PE")
```

I would like that have a data frame with these gene names

```
> head(pccmit$Description)
[1] NDRG4
[2] ATP6V1B2
[3] TF
```

Thank you all, guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(pccmit$Description, "(?<=GN=).*(?= PE)")
```

`(?<=GN=)` looks behind after `GN=` and `(?= PE)` looks ahead of `= PE`, with `.*` matching everything in the middle.

Comment: Just for the cases when there are multiple ` PE` strings in one line, you could add a `?` to the `.*` part to make it non-greedy.. complete regex-pattern would become `"(?<=GN=).*?(?= PE)"`

Answer (score 7):

Here are some alternatives.  No packages are used except for (5).

**1) sub** Using `Lines` shown in the Note at the end and assuming that the gene name does not include any whitespace, this matches everything up to GN=, then captures subsequent non-whitespace and then matches everything replacing everything with the captured portion, i.e. the non-whitespace following GN=.  No packages are used.

```
sub(".*GN=(\\S+).*", "\\1", Lines)
## [1] "NDRG4"    "ATP6V1B2" "TF"       "GLS"      "AK1"      "SFXN1"
```

**2)** Another approach is to remove everything up to and including GN= and then everything from the subsequent whitespace onwards:

```
gsub(".*GN=|\\s.*", "", Lines)
## [1] "NDRG4"    "ATP6V1B2" "TF"       "GLS"      "AK1"      "SFXN1"
```

**3) read.dcf** Another alternative is to convert the data into DCF format and then read it in using `read.dcf`.  This will parse all fields and derive their names from the data itself producing matrix `m`.

```
g <- paste0("\nX:", gsub("(\\S+)=", "\n\\1:", Lines))

m <- read.dcf(textConnection(g))
m
##      X                                               OS             GN         PE  SV 
## [1,] "Protein NDRG4"                                 "Homo sapiens" "NDRG4"    "1" "2"
## [2,] "V-type proton ATPase subunit B_ brain isoform" "Homo sapiens" "ATP6V1B2" "1" "3"
## [3,] "Serotransferrin"                               "Homo sapiens" "TF"       "1" "3"
## [4,] "Glutaminase kidney isoform_ mitochondrial"     "Homo sapiens" "GLS"      "1" "1"
## [5,] "Adenylate kinase isoenzyme 1"                  "Homo sapiens" "AK1"      "1" "3"
## [6,] "Sideroflexin-1"                                "Homo sapiens" "SFXN1"    "1" "4"

m[, "GN"]
## [1] "NDRG4"    "ATP6V1B2" "TF"       "GLS"      "AK1"      "SFXN1"
```

**4) strcapture** Another appeoach to parsing all fields is to use `strcapture`.  This returns a data frame whereas `read.dcf` returns a matrix.  This solution requires that we specify the fields whereas (3) derives them.

```
strcapture("(.*) OS=(.*) GN=(.*) PE=(.*) SV=(.*)", Lines,
  list(X = character(0), OS = character(0), GN = character(0), 
    PE = numeric(0), SV = numeric(0)))
```

giving this data.frame:

```
                                              X           OS       GN PE SV
1                                 Protein NDRG4 Homo sapiens    NDRG4  1  2
2 V-type proton ATPase subunit B_ brain isoform Homo sapiens ATP6V1B2  1  3
3                               Serotransferrin Homo sapiens       TF  1  3
4     Glutaminase kidney isoform_ mitochondrial Homo sapiens      GLS  1  1
5                  Adenylate kinase isoenzyme 1 Homo sapiens      AK1  1  3
6                                Sideroflexin-1 Homo sapiens    SFXN1  1  4
```

If `DF` is that data frame then DF$GN are the gene names.

**5) strapplyc**  Specify a pattern consisting of GN= followed by non-whitespace and put the latter in a capture group which is returned.  This one has the simplest regular expression of any of the alternatives here.

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(Lines, "GN=(\\S+)", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "NDRG4"    "ATP6V1B2" "TF"       "GLS"      "AK1"      "SFXN1"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- c("Protein NDRG4 OS=Homo sapiens GN=NDRG4 PE=1 SV=2",
 "V-type proton ATPase subunit B_ brain isoform OS=Homo sapiens GN=ATP6V1B2 PE=1 SV=3",
 "Serotransferrin OS=Homo sapiens GN=TF PE=1 SV=3",
 "Glutaminase kidney isoform_ mitochondrial OS=Homo sapiens GN=GLS PE=1 SV=1",
 "Adenylate kinase isoenzyme 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=AK1 PE=1 SV=3",        
 "Sideroflexin-1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=SFXN1 PE=1 SV=4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way (base R) which is certainly not good compared to other answers here but okay (I guess) if you are not good with regex -

```
x <- "Protein NDRG4 OS=Homo sapiens GN=NDRG4 PE=1 SV=2"

strsplit(x, " ") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  grep(pattern = "GN=", ., value = T) %>% 
  sub("GN=", "", .)

[1] "NDRG4"
```

Answer (score 0):

an other base approach could be:

```
regmatches( Lines, gregexpr( "(?<=GN=).*?(?= PE)", Lines, perl = TRUE ) )
```